# apply a function on the columns from the list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of columns, whose values in the dataframe I want to convert to Decimal

```
column_list = ['Parameter 1', 'Parameter 2' ... 'Parameter N']
```

The data in a dataframe looks like this

```
Name | Parameter 1 | Parameter 2 | Surname | ... | Parameter N | ...
```

How to achieve that? If it I had a limited set of column names I could probably do something like `df['Parameter 1'] = df['Parameter 1'].apply` or something or maybe even with `lambda row: ...` etc.

But I am not sure how to achieve that if I have a list of columns that I want to update. Should I just iterate over the items like this for example?

```
for column_name in column_list:
    df[column_name] = Decimal(df[column_name])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Decimal` needs to be applied on each individual value, so you must use  [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df[column_list] = df[column_list].applymap(Decimal)
```

Or with your loop:

```
for column_name in column_list:
    df[column_name] = df[column_name].apply(Decimal)
```